# How to open new doccument tab in gedit and send text flow into it from terminal?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, gedit, krusader

I want to make Krusader User Action which lists selected files. I know I can do it in terminal like `ls -1 > list.txt` and than delete unwanted.
But I'm looking something like `gedit newDoc.txt < %aList("Selected")%`.

I checked Gedit help and Google. Did not found how to send text in Gedit, only how to open new documents or existing documents. Is my idea possible at all?

When I try `gedit newDoc newText` it creates two tabs with name "newDoc" and "newText".

ps: how to list files in current dir with full paths like in TotalCommander?

UPD:
`%aList("Selected")% | gedit -` — does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indicate that `gedit` is supposed to read from standard input, [by specifying `-` as an argument](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=476506#15):

```
ls | gedit -
```

To list absolute paths:

```
printf "$PWD/%s\n" * | gedit -
```

`$PWD` contains the absolute path of the current directory.

I don't know what `krusader` is, but assuming a krusader user action is like a Nautilus action, you might have to wrap the command in `sh -c`, and perhaps escape `%`:

```
sh -c 'printf "$PWD/\%s\n" * | gedit -'
```

Replace `*` with appropriate placeholders (which would be `%F` in Nautilus Actions.)

Comment: Yes, good general advice, but not work in Krusader, may be some bug.